# Get top N elements from array in descending order

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `[2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2]` and I want to get top 3 value indexes in descending order. So my output should be [1,4,0] which are the indexes of top 3 elements of the array in descending order. (Similar item indexes are tolerated). I am using bottelneck which is doing my job partially.

```
import bottleneck
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2])
b = np.array(bottleneck.argpartsort(-a, 3)[:3])
print(b)
```

which gives `[4 1 5]` which are the correct top 3(n) indexes of the array but not in the descending order. Is there any built-in function to adjust this output to provide descending order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.argsort`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2])
b = np.argsort(a)[-3:]
b = b[::-1]
```

Note: The last two lines can further be simplified to (although with not much computational advantage)

```
b = np.argsort(a)[-3:][::-1]
# or, as juanpa suggested
b = np.argsort(a)[-1:-4:-1]
```

All give the following value of `b`

```
array([1, 4, 6])
```

Comment: You can do the reversing and slicing in one step: `np.array(np.argsort(a))[-1:-4:-1]`

Comment: Aah nice. Thanks for the heads up! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe `bottleneck.argpartsort` does something similar to [`np.argpartiton`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html). So, let's use that. Now, with `np.argpartiton` instead of `3`, we need to use `range(3)` to keep the sorted order. With just a scalar, `argpartiton` won't sort those `3` elements, but with `range(3)`, it will.

Let's give an example here to showcase that -

```
In [360]: a
Out[360]: 
array([ 0.6082239 ,  0.74932587,  0.50574681,  0.85241966,  0.91742228,
        0.9984438 ,  0.6876266 ,  0.90651069,  0.53746683,  0.70674607])

In [361]: np.argpartition(-a,3) # 4,5,7 are the top 3, but not in sorted order
Out[361]: array([4, 5, 7, 3, 1, 9, 6, 2, 8, 0])

In [362]: np.argpartition(-a,range(3)) # Sorted order maintained for top 3
Out[362]: array([5, 4, 7, 3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 8, 9])
```

Additionally with `np.argpartiton` it won't sort the remaining elements in the array and thus providing runtime benefit there. This would be hugely beneficial if we are looking to get top `N` elements in sorted order, where `N` is a relatively smaller number than the length of the array.

Thus, we would have an implementation with `np.argpartiton`, like so -

```
a[np.argpartition(-a,range(3))[:3]]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [342]: a = np.random.rand(10000)

In [343]: %timeit a[np.argsort(a)[-1:-4:-1]] #@R. S. Nikhil Krishna's soln
1000 loops, best of 3: 907 µs per loop

In [344]: %timeit a[np.argpartition(-a,range(3))[:3]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.9 µs per loop
```